# How to authenticate users with Aws Cognito and Aws Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

We are building an application with mobile authentication and we decided to use Aws. I searched a little and decided to use Aws Cognito. I read the documentation and while reading I noticed that, for the application side I need to use Aws Amplify. I tried some examples but I am not sure I understand the concept right.

Can you give me some insight about this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Cognito is a managed Identity Provider in the cloud, it provides you with a user repository, federation, GUI for signin, signup, lost password and other user flows, it supports OTP, email address verification etc ...

It can be integrated into your app through the provided UI or through its API if you want to control the look and feel of theusre interfaces.

Amplify is a command line tool and client library to make it easy to provision and to use cloud services, including Cognito, from your web or mobile application.

The Amplify CLI will help you to provision Cognito in the cloud, without requiring you to click through all the options in the console.  The Amplify client side library will provide high level programming constructs to make it easy to access cloud based services, such as Cognito, from your apps.

You can watch this 45 minute talk that shows Amplify in action : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxOcvOMnAuQ and this github repo with a sample application : https://github.com/sebsto/amplify-react-workshop

Comment: So I don't have use Amplify with Cognito but it is recommended.

Comment: That's correct.  AMplify CLI and Library are a helper (fewer configuration steps, opiniated default configuration & high level class library).  But you are not obliged to use it.  You can use Cognito API straigth from your app